# Sencha / Extjs 4 with GeoExt 2 - How to use

Tags: geoext, ext-js

I'm working on Sencha Architect 2 - extjs 4
i found out that GeoExt doesn't work with extjs 4. but i really need to use it so i searched and end up here https://github.com/geoext/geoext2

I'm trying to something like examples so i just add :

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    disableCaching: false,
    paths: {
        GeoExt: "../geoext-2/src/GeoExt",
        // for dev use
        Ext: "http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.0-gpl/src"
        // for build purpose
        //Ext: "extjs-4.1.0/src"
    }
});
```

to my app.js file. but i keep getting "GeoExt is not defined" error message.

anyone could help me with that ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with apostrophes?

For me, this works:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
 enabled:true,
 disableCaching: true,
 paths: {
  'Ext': '/lib/extjs-4.1.1/src'
  ,'Ext.ux' : '/lib/extjs-4.1.1/examples/ux'
  // 'Ext'      : 'http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1-gpl/src'
  //,'Ext.ux'   : 'http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1-gpl/examples/ux'
  ,'GeoExt' : '/lib/GeoExt/src/GeoExt'
  ,'VT.ux'  : 'app/ux'
  ,'VT'     : 'app'
  }
});
```

---